# Get row and column index of pandas cells based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains numbers only.

I want to get the (row_index, column_index) list of all the cells with value >= 1.

I wrote a nested for loop, but indeed it is very slow.

```
res= []
for i in range (df.shape[0]):
    for j in range (i+1, df.shape[0]):
        if df.iloc[i,j] >= 1:
            res.append ([i,j,df.iloc[i,j]])
```

Is there a faster way to do the task? The matrix is symmetric so I only consider a half of the dataframe.

Dataframe:

```
1 2 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
```

Expected output:

```
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
```

The first line of the expected out (0 0 1) means that at row 0, column 0, the cell value is >= 1 and it is 1.

Comment: kindly share the dataframe, with the expected output

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) then filter for values [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) 1:

```
output = (
    df.stack()
        .loc[lambda f: f.ge(1)]
        .rename_axis(['index', 'column'])
        .reset_index(name='value')
)
```

`output`:

```
   index  column  value
0      0       0      1
1      0       1      2
2      1       2      1
3      2       1      1
```

---

`stack` reshapes the DataFrame so columns and row indexes are in rows:

```
output = df.stack()
```

```
0  0    1
   1    2
   2    0
1  0    0
   1    0
   2    1
2  0    0
   1    1
   2    0
dtype: int64
```

`loc` can be used to chain filters:

```
output = df.stack().loc[lambda f: f.ge(1)]
```

This could also be done in 2 steps:

```
output = df.stack()
output = output[output.ge(1)]
```

```
0  0    1
   1    2
1  2    1
2  1    1
dtype: int64
```

[`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to add labels to the MultiIndex:

```
output = (
    df.stack()
        .loc[lambda f: f.ge(1)]
        .rename_axis(['index', 'column'])
)
```

```
index  column
0      0          1
       1          2
1      2          1
2      1          1
dtype: int64
```

Then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to turn MultiIndex into columns:

```
output = (
    df.stack()
        .loc[lambda f: f.ge(1)]
        .rename_axis(['index', 'columns'])
        .reset_index(name='value')
)
```

Or

```
output = df.stack()
output = output[output.ge(1)].rename_axis(['index', 'columns']).reset_index()
```

```
   index  column  value
0      0       0      1
1      0       1      2
2      1       2      1
3      2       1      1
```

Answer (score 2):

I like `query`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index='idx', columns='cols')
df.stack().reset_index(name='value').query('value >= 1')
```

Output:

```
   idx  cols  value
0    0     0      1
1    0     1      2
5    1     2      1
7    2     1      1
```

Use `rename_axis` to handle some cleanup column names, then `stack`, `reset_index` and filter dataframe using `query`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way via `melt()`+`sort_values()`:

```
out=(df.reset_index()
       .melt('index',var_name='column')
       .query('value>=1')
       .sort_values('index'))
```

output of `out`:

```
  index     column  value
0   0       0       1
3   0       1       2
7   1       2       1
5   2       1       1
```

Sample dataframe used:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]))
```